# MacBook Pro has to recover from Safe Sleep after 50% of all sleeps, although power is connected

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, memory

When I wake my MacBook Pro from sleep it sometimes has to recover from Safe Sleep, even though the power is connected.

I have installed 16 GB (2x8) RAM myself on my MacBook, however 8 GB is the max supported RAM.

Could this be why it fails to wake from sleep quickly?

Is there an error log stating why it had to recover from Safe Sleep?

By recovering from Safe Sleep I mean this:

[image]

`pmset -g`:

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              0
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 sms                  1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by )
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Answer (score 1):

[Apple says](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1757) the reason is to comply with the European Energy Standards.  It looks like you can [modify the behavior](https://discussions.apple.com/message/21325631#21325631) with some commandline-fu:

```
sudo pmset -a autopoweroffdelay 86400
```

will send your MacBook Pro to safe sleep after 24 hours instead of the default 4 hours.